# Encoder-Decoder RNN - how to control the decoder input at timestep level?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, lstm, missing-data

My input time series X have missing values marked with 0s. I want to develop an encoder-decoder RNN where, at the t-th timestep, the decoder receives [X_t, H_t] if X_t is observed, otherwise [~X_t, H_t] (where ~X_t is not ground truth, but rather predicted by the decoder at time t-1). Using Tensorflow/Keras, how to control the decoder input for each timestep?

Comment: Does this helps https://www.tensorflow.org/text/tutorials/nmt_with_attention#the_encoderdecoder_model